# How to use react-router match params fetching data from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-router

I have a little contacts app that shows a list of contacts. I would like to be able to render a route when a contact is clicked on from the contacts page. I have no problem rendering the complete list of contacts I just can't get a single contact to render
My Contacts component looks like this

```
class Contacts extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  contactslist: []
 }
}

componentWillMount(){
let contactslistRef = firebase.database().ref('contactslist');
let _this = this;
contactslistRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
let contactslist = snapshot.val();
  let newState = [];
  for (let contact in contactslist) {
    newState.push({
      id: contact,
      name: contactslist[contact].name,
      phone: contactslist[contact].phone
    });
  }
console.log(snapshot.val());
_this.setState({
contactslist: newState

  });
 })
}
render() {
return (
  <div className='app'>
  <h1>Contacts list</h1>
  <ul>
  {this.state.contactslist.map((contact) => {
    return (
      <li key={contact.id}>
      <Link to={`/contact/${contact.id}`}>{contact.name} {contact.phone}</Link>
      </li>
    )
  })}</ul>
</div>

);
}
}
export default Contacts;
```

My Contact component is like this

```
const Contact = (props) => {
const contact = (props.match.params.id)
return (
<div className="card">
  <h1>{props.name}</h1>
  <h2>Phone:{props.phone}</h2>
  <Link to='/contacts'>Back</Link>
</div>
 )
}

export default Contact;
```

And I have a Main component that contains all the routes

```
const Main = () => (
<main>
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
  <Route path='/contacts' component={Contacts} />
  <Route path='contacts/:id' component={Contact} />
</Switch>
</main>
)
export default Main
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get parameter from url and receive detail information about your contact from firebase.

```
class Contact extends React.Component{
  state = {
    detail: {}
  } 

  componentDidMount(){
   const {id} = this.props.match.params;
   const _this = this;

   if (!id) return;

   const detail = firebase.database().ref('contactslist/' + id);

   detail.on('value', function(snapshot) {
     _this.setState({
       detail: snapshot.val()
     });
   });
  }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what do I put in the render and return?